# IE failed to redirect the page

Tags: c#, internet-explorer

I have got a problem that I am redirecting the page to other domain using response.redirect, It works well in Firefox, but in ie it shows the blank web page. when i tried to see what happens in fiddler, it says that object Moved, but the redirect doesn't happens here. Interesting thing is I couldn't replicate this in my local environment, but it happens in my DEV and QAL servers.

When i tried in dev & QAL servers, IE redirects it to the desired page.Can anyone help??

Comment: Show what have you done?

Comment: What are the full set of headers on the HTTP Response? (You can easily copy these from Fiddler).

Answer (score 0):

**Try to clear cache in Internet Explorer**

You probably set redirect to some page and then change it to other page.

Sometimes when permanent redirect occurs, IE cache it and don't ask for a page one more time but get the redirect path from cache. IE don't even refresh the address textbox which is misleading.